Unable to get my lowercase W key to function on Manjaro Linux no matter what I try
I am currently having issues getting my lowercase "w" key to work and be detected by input, but nothing that I do seems to work at all. I began troubleshooting the problem by going to *Settings -> Input Devices -> Keyboard, and tried to mess around with the keyboard layout in order to find the problem, but to no avail.
I even tried installing the AUR input-remapper-git to see if I could remap the w key to function easier, but still no luck.
I am providing the output of the cmd showkey > output, as well as a GIF of an onscreen keyboard + what my browser search bar looks like when I press the key. The reason for the GIF is because i can tell that pressing "w" does something, I just can't figure out what.
showkey > output.txt
if you are trying this under X, it might not work
since the X server is also reading /dev/console ]

press any key (program terminates 10s after last keypress)...
keycode  28 release
keycode  31 press
keycode  31 release
keycode  45 press
keycode  45 release
keycode  17 press
keycode  17 release

--
Here you can see a Keyboard Preview of my current keyboard, when searching on Firefox, it shows search suggestions until I press the key w, then they all disappear until I press another key.

